# Proper unit tests for decorator class in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking, decorator, mapstruct

I have a mapstruct class with a decorator. Now I need to unit test both the mapstruct and the decorator. Couldn't find any proper example to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share your attempt?